# how to fetch first ul element items from nokogiri in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

i am having the following html that contains 2 UL elements.

```
<ul>
```

1

2

3

```
<ul>
```

4

5

6

i am using the following logic to get the data from only first Ul element. but iam getting data from both ul elements. How can i fetch the data only from a first UL element?

```
uls = xyz_html.css('ul li')
  uls.each do |li|
    
      @ul_list_1 << li.text
    
  end
```

@ul_list_1 displaying all the data as an array like [1, 2,3, 4,5,6] but i need output [1,2,3]

i tried the following logic also but i did not get the output

```
uls = xyz_html.css('ul:first-child li')
  uls.each do |li|
    
      @ul_list_1 << li.text
    
  end
```

Can some one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-of-type` CSS selector, which returns first occurence of given element, so:

```
xyz_html.css('ul:first-of-type li')
```

More info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/

Comment: Not working. getting li tags from both the ul elements

Comment: Can you paste the exact html you have? Are you sure you are printing results correctly? You can use: `uls.map(&:text)`